# using brackets with javascript import syntax

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I came across a javascript library that uses the following syntax to import libraries:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

What is the difference between the above method and the following?

```
import React, Component, PropTypes from 'react';
```

Comment: The members to import from the module are enclosed in curlybraces

Comment: see also [Javascript (ES6), export const vs export default](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33611812/1048572)

Answer (score 193, accepted):

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

This says:

> Import the **default** export from `'react'` under the name `React` and import the **named** exports `Component` and `PropTypes` under the same names.

This combines the two common syntaxes which you've probably seen

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

The first being used to import and name the default export, the second to import the specified named exports.

As a general rule, most modules will either provide a single, default export, or a list of named exports. It is somewhat less usual for a module to provide both a default export **and** named exports. However, in the case where there is one feature which is most commonly imported, but also additional sub-features, it is a valid design to export the first as the default, and the remaining ones as named exports. It is in such cases you would use the `import` syntax you refer to.

The other answers are somewhere between wrong and confusing, possibly because the MDN documents at the time this question was asked were wrong and confusing. MDN showed the example

```
import name from "module-name";
```

and said `name` is the "name of the object that will receive the imported values." But that's misleading and incorrect; first of all, there is only **one** import value, which will be "received" (why not just say "assigned to", or "used to refer to") `name`, and the import value in this case is the **default export** from the module.

Another way of explaining this is to note that the above import is precisely identical to

```
import { default as name } from "module-name";
```

and the OP's example is precisely identical to

```
import { default as React, Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
```

The MDN documentation went on to show the example

```
import MyModule, {foo, bar} from "my-module.js";
```

and claimed that it means

> Import an entire module's contents, with some also being explicitly named. This inserts `myModule` (sic), `foo`, and `bar` into the current scope. Note that `foo` and `myModule.foo` are the same, as are `bar` and `myModule.bar`

What MDN said here, and what other answers claim based on the incorrect MDN documentation, is absolutely wrong, and may be based on an earlier version of the spec. What this actually does is

> Import the default module export and some explictly named exports. This inserts `MyModule`, `foo`, and `bar` into the current scope. **The export names `foo` and `bar` are *not* accessible via `MyModule`**, which is the *default* export, not some umbrella covering all exports.

(The default module export is the value exported with the `export default` syntax, which could also be `export {foo as default}`.)

The MDN documentation writers may have gotten confused with the following form:

```
import * as MyModule from 'my-module';
```

This imports all exports from `my-module`, and makes them accessible under names such as `MyModule.name`. The default export is also accessible as `MyModule.default`, since the default export is really nothing more than another named export with the name `default`. In this syntax, there is no way to import only a subset of the named exports, although one could import the default export, if there is one, together with all the named exports, with

```
import myModuleDefault, * as myModule from 'my-module';
```

Comment: Babel accepts `from '/path/to/my-module.js'`, although I personally use `from '/path/to/my-module'`.

Comment: With such a detailed explanation you should also add how they are exported in order to be imported like that.

Comment: Thank you for a complete, knowledge and respectful answer that is truly helpful instead of some of the other snide commenters. I appreciate answers like this. Thanks again for being one of the good guys on here.

Answer (score 38):

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
```

This will grab the exported `{ Component, PropTypes }` members from the `'react'` module and assign them to `Component` and `PropTypes`, respectively. `React` will be equal to the module's `default` export.

[As noted by torazaburo below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31098182/2476755), this is the same as

```
import { default as React, Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
```

which is shorthand for

```
import { default as React, Component as Component, PropTypes as PropTypes} from 'react'
```

Here's another example ([link to gist](https://gist.github.com/royhowie/86c25545ed21db78ede6)):

```
// myModule.js
export let a = true
export let b = 42
export let c = 'hello, world!'
// `d` is not exported alone
let d = 'some property only available from default'

// this uses the new object literal notation in es6
// {myVar} expands to { myVar : myVar }, provided myVar exists
// e.g., let test = 22; let o = {test}; `o` is then equal to { test : 22 }
export default { a, b, d }

// example1.js
import something from 'myModule'
console.log(something)
// this yields (note how `c` is not here):
/*
  {
    a : true,
    b : 42,
    d : 'some property only available from default'
  }
*/

// example2.js
import something, { c } from 'myModule'
console.log(something)  // same as above; the `default` export
console.log(c)          // c === 'hello, world!'

// example3.js
import { a, b, d, default as something } from 'myModule'
console.log(a)            // a === true
console.log(b)            // b === 42
console.log(d)            // d === undefined (we didn't export it individually)
console.log(something.d)  // something.d === 'some property...'
```

---

I tested the second example with babel:

```
import test, test3, test2 from './app/lib/queries.js'
console.log(test, test3, test2)
```

and got a syntax error.

```
~/code/repo/tutoring $ babel-node test.js
/Users/royhowie/.node/lib/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/transformation/file/index.js:601
      throw err;
            ^
SyntaxError: /Users/royhowie/code/repo/tutoring/test.js: Unexpected token (1:13)
> 1 | import test, test3, test2 from './app/lib/queries.js'
    |              ^
  2 | 
  3 | console.log(test, test3, test2)
  4 |
```

---

For reference, you can read up on the new [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) documentation from MDN. However, it is apparently in need of technical review. [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer's blog post](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) is a better reference for now.

Comment: *This will grab the { Component, PropTypes } properties from the exports in the 'react' module and assign them to React.* This is incorrect. It assigns the default export to `React`, and the named exports `Component` and `PropTypes` to variables of the same name. Unfortunately, the MDN docs are wrong, as you would find out if you tried it. See http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html. Also, import syntax has absolutely nothing to do with destructuring assignment.

Comment: With regard to your comment about the "new `import` documentation`, reviewing the revision history of that MDN article, the parts you are quoting have not been revised since the page was first written more than a year ago, a period during which the module syntax was changing rapidly.

Comment: @torazaburo I rewrote my answer to be more accurate.

Comment: @royhowie Thank you so much for this example!! Literally saved another hour worth of mindlessly browsing around... I just have one question. In `example3.js` why did it print `undefined` for `console.log(d)`? Since you did `export default { a, b, d }` so you did export it in `myModule.js`.

Comment: @1290 In `myModule.js`, note that `a`, `b`, and `c` were exported individually. This means another file can import them directly with `import { a } from 'myModule'`. On the other hand, `d` is only available via the default export, so another module can access it in two ways: `import thisObjectContainsDefault from 'myModule'` and access it via `thisObjectContainsDefault.d` OR `import { default as wrapperObject }` and `wrapperObject.d`. The benefit of the second approach is that you can also grab items which were individually exported, as can be seen in `example3.js`.

Comment: @royhowie OH I completely missed that. Thank you for taking the time for pointing that out and further explaining. Cleared everything up! :)