# node require() versus es6 import: why doesn't this example work

Tags: javascript, node.js

Isn't ES6 replacing node require()? I've got the following code:

`var sprintf = require("sprintf-js").sprintf;`

This works as advertised. I can just use sprintf(). I'd like to accomplish the same using ES6 import statements:

`import sprintf from 'sprintf-js';`

This does not work. Why not? How can I fix it? Bonus points if you can explain how the exports work inside sprintf-js.

Comment: You probably need to do `import { sprintf } from 'sprintf-js';`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access module exports in a number of ways. [See the MDN article.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

```
import defaultMember from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { member } from "module-name";
import { member as alias } from "module-name";
import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";
import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultMember, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
```

In this case, your syntax would work if you had assigned the export of `sprintf` to be `default`; if you had assigned `sprintf` to the `default` object.

Assuming its not, a correct syntax would incorporate references to the exported method within curly-braces.

```
import { sprintf } from 'sprintf-js';
```

Comment: *"would incorporate a destructured object referencing the method"* Note that the syntax used in `import` statements has nothing to do with destructuring. It only looks similar. Just to prevent any confusion.

Comment: Ah. Interesting point. I might have the wrong impression about the curlybrace syntax on imports. I thought that an equivalent import would be like `import { prop : prop } from 'resource'`, but it clearly doesn't work.

Comment: good discussion curly brace syntax on import: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax

Comment: The sprintf-js module is not mine, so I could not modify it, but your solution works. I should have thought of that myself. Thanks.