# React warning error stops compiling the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I have the following:

nav.jsx component: (everything was working fine till this point)

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "react-router";

class Nav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/test1">test1</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/test2">test2</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

export default Nav;
```

a routes component as follow:

routes.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Router, IndexRoute } from "react-router";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./index.jsx";
import Test1 from "./test1.jsx";
import Test2 from "./test2.jsx";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/test1" component={Test1} />
        <Route path="/test2" component={Test2} />
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

and an index.jsx like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import Nav from "./nav.jsx";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Nav />
                <p> Hello React!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

however I get the following error in the console:

**invariant.js:38 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Nav`.**

Everything was working fine untill I have added the "Nav" component...

[image]

Comment: Have you imported React into your Nav component?

Comment: Yes I have with "import React from 'react';"

Comment: And does it build without the link components in the render method?

Comment: it doesn't render at all, empty screen

Comment: Can you try `import { Link } from 'react-router'` instead of `import Link from 'react-router';`

Comment: Is render also imported?

Does it error when its building?

Try taking out the <Link /> components and see if it renders. What im thinking is perhaps "/test1" and "/test2" dont exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import {Link} from 'react-router'
```

Above should do your job. Can you give it a try once?

Comment: yes it did... I am new to React... why did that solve it?

Comment: Yes sure. You can check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with the following

Also please take a look at https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/Introduction.md

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import Nav from './nav.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <p> Hello React!</p>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```