# What is the difference between " import {foo} form './foo' " and " import foo form './foo' "

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, reactjs

I am new in modern JS world and some things confusing me a little.

In my project I use the following tools:

- `webpack` for build configuration and execution;
- `babel` as I understand used to compile JSX sources into JS;

Suppose I have following `jsx` modules:

**foo.jsx**

```
export default function foo(){}
```

**bar1.jsx**

```
import {foo} from './foo';
```

**bar2.jsx**

```
import foo from './foo';
```

So what is the difference between `foo` in `bar1.jsx` and `bar2.jsx`?

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31096597/251311

Comment: Not sure it is duplicate. May be wording of the question is not entirely clear.
`webpack` produce different result code: 

`var _foo = __webpack_require__(279);
var _foo2 = _interopRequireDefault(_foo);`
and 
`var _foo = __webpack_require__(279);`

Comment: Webpack surely produces different output because those 2 imports are different. Differences are explained in either of the 2 duplicates.

Comment: Got it, thanks.
Simple things in new areas are sometimes introduced into confusion :)