# Rendering a modal in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to trap an onclick method on a React component to create a React Modal.
I've added `react-overlay` as a dependency and added it to my file.

```
import Modal from 'react-overlays';
```

This is the anchor element,

```
<a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick} data-id={image.id}>
```

This is the handleclick method,

```
handleClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let mediaId = event.currentTarget.attributes['data-id'].value;
    this.setState({ overlay: <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close} mediaId={mediaId}/> });
  }
```

I get the following error,

```
Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components).
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.(…)
```

Comment: What is `Modal`? Presumably in your case it is `undefined`

Comment: Modal is the `Modal` component provided by `React` and I've imported it in my file.

Comment: `import { Modal } from ...` Then read http://stackoverflow.com/q/31096597/251311

Comment: This is the error that I get, on deconstructing, `invariant.js:38 Uncaught Error: onlyChild must be passed a children with exactly one child.`

Comment: Show the corresponding code, we have no idea what you are currently running there.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem and got around it by creating a Modal-component.

```
import Modal from 'react-modal'


export default class CustomModal extends React.Component {

    constructor () {
        super();
        this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
        this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            open: false
        }
    }

    openModal () { this.setState(
        {open: true});
        $(function(){
            $("#custom-modal").appendTo("body");
        });
    }

    closeModal () {

        this.setState({open: false});
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        $(function(){
            $("#custom-modal").appendTo("body");
        });
    }

    render () {

        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.openModal}>My modal</button>
                <Modal id="custom-modal" isOpen={this.state.open} onRequestClose={this.closeModal}>

                     // Modal body content here

                    <button onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

And then using it like this:

```
import CustomModal from '../components/CustomModal'
...
<li><CustomModal/></li>
```

Hope this is of any help.

Comment: Could you explain what you're doing with the jquery function and inside componentDidMount. I'm pretty new to javascript and React. Also I'm not using jquery in my project. Can I now launch this using my handleClick function.

Comment: The jquery-funcitons is inserting the modal html-code to the body of the document when we open it. Is there a specfic reason as to why you are not using jquery in the project? Otherwise you can easily implement it by adding  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: In the head of your index html file that is.

Answer (score 0):

Your state should contain information that allows you to render the modal, but not the modal itself.

It's highly unusually to store components in state.

Try this:

1. Store a flag in your state to indicate whether the modal should be shown.
2. Set the flag in `handleClick()`
3. In `render()`, render the modal if the flag is set.

Let me know if you need an example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're importing `undefined`..

Also, take a look at https://github.com/fckt/react-layer-stack. This is universal and clean way to solve the "modal problem" in React. Demo - https://fckt.github.io/react-layer-stack/

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still has an issue with this, a modern approach is to build the modal using React hooks. as shown below

```
import React from 'react';
import './modal.css';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';

const Modal = (props) => {
  const { closeModal } = props;

  const closeicon = () => (
    <FontAwesome
    name="times"
    onClick={closeModal}
    style={{
      color: '#000000',
      padding: '10px',
      cursor: 'pointer',
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      border: 0,
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '0.3rem',
      right: '0.5rem',
    }}
    />
  );

  return (
    <div className="overlay">
      <div className="content">
        { closeicon() }
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


export default Modal;
```

The css is as shown below

```
.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    display: block; 
    overflow: auto; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    z-index: 999; 
    cursor: pointer;
  }

.content {
        margin: 15% auto;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        width: 50vw;
        padding: 2rem;
        position: relative;
  }
```

So you can use the modal component like this

```
 const [status, setStatus] = useState(false);

//this button will trigger the modal

<button onClick={() => setStatus(true)}>Open Modal</button>


{
status && (
<Modal closeModal={() => setStatus(false)}><p>hello worls</p></Modal>
         )
}
```

No need to worry about responsiveness It's been taken care of in the styling.

For further explanation, you can check this link
https://dev.to/adeyemiadekore2/how-to-build-a-reusable-and-responsive-modal-in-react-from-scratch-1o0f

Comment: This is almost link-only. Also, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion