# HOW TO OPEN console.log in modal in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using react and axios for post the data. and i want response in modal after post the data. currently i am getting data in console.log but i want to see these data in modal.
currently i m using alert but getting undefined in alert.

```
axios.post("https://api_use.com/aof/upload/broker/existing/user/", data, options).then(res => { 
    console.log(res)
    this.setState({ avatar: res.data.url, uploadPercentage: 100 }, ()=>{
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ uploadPercentage: 0 })
      }, 1000);

      console.log(res.data.failed)

     **alert(console.log(res.data.failed));**
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Console.log by definition only logs to the developer console. To display in an `alert`, simply remove the use of `console.log`:

```
alert(res.data.failed);
```

It is possible in JavaScript to redefine `console.log` ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404874/intersect-javascript-console-log-calls-and-send-the-data-to-my-own-logger-func)), but this is an advanced use case that I would not recommend for the simple code you are showing above.

For a modal popup other than the standard `alert`, you'll probably want to install something like [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal). For several variations on how to achieve this, see [Rendering a modal in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444788/rendering-a-modal-in-react)

Comment: Thank you. can i see these data in modal? @Sfuqua

Comment: `alert(...)` will show you a modal with the message

Comment: i want a modal just like material ui or bootstrap