# extending React.Component vs Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just got in a project on React Native, where I constantly see classes extending both `React.Component` and `Component` itself.

Examples:

`class SomeView extends React.Component`

or

`class OtherView extends Component`

in both of them we are importing `React, {Component} from React`

Is there any actual difference, if so, which one? Didn't found any info on the web. Cheers!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using brackets with javascript import syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax)

Comment: When you do `import { Component } from 'react'`, you are importing `React.Component`. Meaning that if you, at the beginning of the file, write `import React, { Component } from 'react'`, `React.Component` refers to the exact same class as `Component`, making both syntaxes you mentioned valid.

Comment: @TadeášPeták That's exactly what I thought, just needed some confirmation. Thanks! :)

Comment: There is actually a difference. You may have multiple packages that export a Component. So, extending from React.Component makes clear and explicit which component is being used.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well you can do whatever you want really.

Doing `import { Component } from 'react'` is effectively the same thing as `React.Component`.

The `import { Component } from 'react'` syntax is called a [**Named Import**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

> The import statement is used to import bindings which are exported by another module.

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
```

Comment: `import { Component } from 'react'` is not destructuring. It is a named import.

Answer (score 1):

```
import {Component} from 'react';
```

This is called named module import.

[The module to import from. This is often a relative or absolute path name to the .js file containing the module, excluding the .js extension. Certain bundlers may permit or require the use of the extension; check your environment. Only single quotes and double quotes Strings are allowed.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)