# How does this Javascript import statement work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-import

I'm currently learning React , The first line of react component is a import statement like below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

It work fine. But if I move `React` into the `{}` like this:

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';
```

It does not work.

**What is happening here ???**

Comment: [`import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: No bro, i'm not asking about when and why i use the curly branch. I'm asking about why React is outside of the curly branch. and why it not work if i move react inside the curly branch.

Comment: Oh, does its for default export ???  @Jai

Comment: @kousheralampranto for  a better explanation you can go through the link shared by **tanmay**.

Comment: Ok bro , I got it...  Thank you @tanmay

Comment: And @jai  thank you too bro..

Comment: Check this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax

Comment: ok bro.. & thank you @Jayavel