# Creating variables for destructured objects in addition to their properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have:

```
const { state: { mode } } = this

console.log(mode) //'mode'
console.log(state) //undefined
```

I want to declare the `state` variable as well.

Is there a way to destructure this without breaking it into two statements?

```
const { state } = this
const { mode } = state
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure, just use a comma as if you were destructing another property of the parent object:

```js
const obj = { state: { mode: 'str' }};
const { state: { mode }, state } = obj;
console.log(mode);
console.log(state);
```

Note that this looks very similar to, but is [not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax) as the following `import` syntax you may have seen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
```

Here, the variables in brackets are *named exports*, while the plain variable is the default export, which is entirely different from nested objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can destructure the `state` to a variable as well:

```js
const { state, state: { mode } } = { state: { mode: 'mode' } };

console.log(mode) // 'mode'
console.log(state) // { mode: 'mode' }
```

Answer (score 0):

While all the other answer here suggested a word around to get values, but i am adding this answer to explain why we getting only the deep most nested value

```
let state = {
    state: {
      mode : 'some value'
 }
}

const { state: { mode } } = state
```

When you do nested destructing you will be complied to something like this

```
var state = {
  state: {
    mode: 'some value'
  }
};
var mode = state.state.mode;  // this is how your de-structuring is interpreted
```

It is not creating a separate variable for each of the property,