# Importing Dygraph from dygraphs not working

Tags: angular, typescript, dygraphs

I am trying to use [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) in Angular CLI 7, but the import is not working. I installed it first using `npm install --save dygraphs` and in my imports i wrote `import { Dygraph } from 'dygraphs';`, but the error in TSLint still says `File '/home/[...]/node_modules/@types/dygraphs/index.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)`.

The same error message appears for the `chart.js` import, but here, it works fine. All graphs are displayed correctly.

Also, the compiler says `error TS2305: Module '"dygraphs"' has no exported member 'Dygraph'.`, which would mean that the module imports fine but the member is not found?

In the web console, the error message is `RROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: dygraphs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_6__.Dygraph is not a constructor`. I am trying to create a graph like this:

```
private config = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
];
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("div_g"), this.config,
    {
        drawPoints: true,
        showRoller: true,
        valueRange: [0.0, 1.2],
        labels: ['Time', 'Random']
    });
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your import is incorrect:

```
import { Dygraph } from 'dygraphs';
```

should be

```
import Dygraph from 'dygraphs';
```

For an explanation, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31098182/4694994).