# How to import a object in JS

Tags: javascript, import, lwc

Constants.js

```
const CONTACT_SCHEMA = {
    CONTACT: CONTACT_OBJECT,
    FIRSTNAME: FIRSTNAME_FIELD,
    LASTNAME: LASTNAME_FIELD,
    EMAIL: EMAIL_FIELD,
    PHONE: PHONE_FIELD,
    FAX: FAX_FIELD
};

export default CONTACT_SCHEMA;
```

CreateContact.js

```
import { CONTACT_SCHEMA } from 'Constants';
```

How can I import **CONTACT_SCHEMA** from **Constants.js** into **CreateContact.js**

Here I am using this thing in lightning web component. I write all constants in the constants.js file and now i want to use these constants in the CreateContact file. But it's giving some error

> Invalid reference Constants of type module in file createContact.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using brackets with javascript import syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax)

Comment: No, I tried that already but that's not working

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
const CONTACT_SCHEMA = {
    CONTACT: CONTACT_OBJECT,
    FIRSTNAME: FIRSTNAME_FIELD,
    LASTNAME: LASTNAME_FIELD,
    EMAIL: EMAIL_FIELD,
    PHONE: PHONE_FIELD,
    FAX: FAX_FIELD
};

export default CONTACT_SCHEMA
```

And import

```
import  CONTACT_SCHEMA  from 'Constant'
```

Though importing like this:

```
import { CONTACT_SCHEMA } from 'Constant';
```

If you're not exporting with the default keyword

Should work. Currently it looks like Constant.js is in the same folder as the file you're importing it from, if that's not true then you'll need to amend the import to reflect. it.

**To be safe always assume case sensitivity matters.**

Comment: "Invalid reference constants of type module in file CreateContact.js" This error message I am getting. I tried both import statements.

Comment: Can you update your question with what you've tried.

Comment: If you have a default export then you don't need the { }  on the import.  Read the link Daedalus posted. 
Change import { CONTACT_SCHEMA } from 'Constants'; to
import CONTACT_SCHEMA  from 'Constant'; You had an extra s, apologies if you copied that straight from my example where I added the 's' in error.

Comment: File name is constants.js by mistake I forgort to write that here. I tried direct CONTACT_SCHEMA but again same error.

Comment: Are Constants.js and CreateContact.js in the same folder?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKxuO.png  Here you can see my files

Comment: Yes both files are in the same folder

Comment: The import paths need to have a path relative to the root of the project.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules 
Look under the heading "Importing features into your script"
So it might be '/lwc/createContact/constants' in you case, but I cannot see your whole project structure.

Comment: import CONTACT_SCHEMA from '/lwc/createContact/constants';  With this again same errror. can we make a hangout call? I will be thankful to you.

Comment: Update the question with what your most up to date solution.