# Attempted import error: 'reactstrap' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Table')

Tags: reactjs, import, export, version, reactstrap

I even tried `import {Table} from 'reactstrap';` i.e with the curly braces. When used with the curly braces data is coming but not as a table. My reactstrap is also of the latest version.
This is the error being shown: **Attempted import error: 'reactstrap' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Table').**
This is my Assignment.js.

```
import Table from 'reactstrap';

class Assignment extends Component{

  render(){
      return(

     <Table dark>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
          <td>Otto</td>
          <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
          <td>Thornton</td>
          <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
          <td>the Bird</td>
          <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </Table>

      )
  }
}
```

export default Assignment;`

Comment: A 5 second google search shows from the [docs](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tables/) that it should be imported as `import { Table } from 'reactstrap';`. If you attempted that like you say, you would have either seen it work, or gotten a different error.

Comment: [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax) about the differences between named and default imports.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using brackets with javascript import syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096597/using-brackets-with-javascript-import-syntax)

Comment: Ya the error is gone but table is still not there. Just the data. I got it it was an isssue with bootstrap. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/home-upgrading--page

**Removed components**

`InputGroupAddon:` This in no longer needed in Bootstrap 5, you can now add `Buttons`, `Inputs` directly to `InputGroups` in the order you wish.

`InputGroupButtonDropdown:` This can now be replaced with a regular `Dropdown` component.

`CustomInput:` These are no longer needed in Bootstrap 5, since all form inputs will be styled by Bootstrap instead of browser default. The existing `Input` component now supports *file*, *select*, *switch*, and *range* types.

`Jumbotron:` Jumbotrons have been removed from Bootstrap 5, can be replaced with `<div class="rounded px-3 px-sm-4 py-3 py-sm-5">`. `Jumbotron` *fluid* can be replaced with `<div class="bg-light mb-4 py-3 py-sm-5">`.

**Components with breaking changes**

`Tooltip/Popover/DropdownMenu:` The *modifiers* prop will now conform to the new *popper2 modifiers*, which take an array instead of an object. *offset* prop is now an array of 2 numbers that represent *skidding* and *distance*.

`ModalHeader/ToastHeader:` Bootstrap 5 no longer supports *custom close icons*, so this feature was removed from `ModalHeader` and `ToastHeader`.

`Dropdown/DropdownMenu:` The *left* and *right* properties are deprecated, but still supported for backwards compatibility. Now replaced with *start* and *end* in Bootstrap 5.